# Android Studio: rendering fails for WearableListView

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use `WearableListView` within my app and tried out some samples, including Wearable Notifications.
With every sample tried I will get an error message when looking to the layout in design mode.

E.g. the layout of the Wearable Notifications sample is quite simple:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:scrollbars="none"
     android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

and throws `Rendering` problems - The following class could not be instantiated: - 
`android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView`

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service: accessibility

at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService (BridgeContext.java:463).....`

Although of this problem the app will compile and run successfully. What goes wrong here? I am running Android studio 1.1 preview 2, the project is using API 21.

Comment: You need to select the Android version for rendering as API 21: Android 5.0W

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you have set up your project correctly:

Android studio is still in beta, 
I would assume this is a bug. 
I have seen very similar ones displaying cardviews from the support packages.
have a look on here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=studio&cells=tiles and see if the bug has already been reported if not, look at the guidelines and raise your bug.